# Python magic command %store not working on Google Colab notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to share data between two different Google Colab notebooks.

Google Colab Notebook 1:

```
(...)
data_structure = scaler.fit_transform(features)
%store data_structure
```

Google Colab Notebook 2:

```
%store -r data_structure 
print(data_structure)
```

After running Notebook 1, I get the message: **Stored 'data_structure' (ndarray)** . However, when I run Notebook 2, I get the message error: **no stored variable data_structure ... NameError: name 'data_structure' is not defined**.

Since the notebooks are in different directories, I also tried to run them in the same directory. However, I get the same problem.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

IPython sotre database is located under `%IPYTHONDIR/<profile_name/db/autorestore/<variable_name>`. Since this path is local, it is machine-specific, so if you open two notebooks in Colab, they are not sharing the same store database.

You can mount google drive in both notebooks as shared storage and use pickle to serialize/deserialize data.